# What is my command path?

Tags: java, path

I am new to Java. Just got "Murachs Java SE 6" yesterday.

The first chapter has you set the command path and I understand how to set the path. I don't understand how to find my path.

Actually it doesn't really say much about where to look for it or what I am supposed to set so I am a little confused. I understand the concept I just don't understand what exactly its looking for.

Comment: What OS? In Windows command prompt, `echo %PATH%`, Unix-y, `echo $PATH`. You can set it via a settings dialog, but I prefer using a script since I need to change it fairly frequently.

Comment: Tell the operating system you're using.

Comment: Windows 7 64bit (sorry I guess that would have helped)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the PATH environment variable for your shell.  Its not specific to Java. You can print it by typing `echo %PATH%` in DOS or `echo $PATH` in a unix shell.

Answer (score 1):

If you open a command prompt (not sure what operating system you use but if that is Windows try to type cmd in the `start -> run` menu).  Then you type path and it will show your path variable usually as

`PATH=thenalistofvariablesseparatedbysemicolons`

Hope it helps